# Opening CSS modal dialog using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css, modal-dialog

I have following **Modal Dialog** (popup) using only **CSS3** in my asp page for user registration:

HTML :

```
<%-- Modal PopUp starts here--%>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div> 
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close" onclick="DisableAllPopUpTxt()">X</a>
    <table style="width:100%;">
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
          <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMSG2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FF3300" Text="Email ID Already Taken " Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
          <input id="txtCustFName" name="txtCustFName" type="text" required placeholder="Enter Your First Name" style="width: 80%" />
        </td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
          <input id="txtCustLName" name="txtCustLName" type="text" required placeholder="Enter Your Last Name" style="width: 80%" />
        </td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
          <input id="txtCustREmail" name="txtCustREmail" type="email" required placeholder="Enter Valid Email ID" style="width: 80%" />
        </td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
          <input id="txtCustRPwd" name="txtCustRPwd" type="password" required placeholder="Enter Password" style="width: 80%" />
        </td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
          <input id="txtCustRePwd" name="txtCustRePwd" type="password" required placeholder="ReType Password" style="width: 80%" />
        </td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
          <input id="txtCustPh" name="txtCustPh" type="number" size="10" min="10" max="10" required placeholder="Enter Valid Mobile No" style="width: 80%" />
        </td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="style1" style="text-align: center; width: 100%;" onclick="btnSignUp()">
          <asp:Button ID="btnSingUp" runat="server" onclick="signUp" Text="Login" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<%--Modal PopUp Ends Here--%>
```

CSS :

```
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
  background: #00d9ff;
}
```

In my asp page I've following anchor tag which is used to display the popup:

```
<a href="#openModal" id="DialogLink" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold">Register</a>
```

Now the problem is:

As this is registration form, I want server side validation of existing email id .
If user entered email id already exist in DB I want to reopen the above modal dialog with an error message Email ID already exist.

I m not able to reopen that dialog box.
Is there any way to do this using js?

Answer (score 0):

My advice, use the css class to open and close.
add a css class,

```
.opend
{
 opacity :1;
}
```

Add the event onclick to the link,

```
<a onclick='document.getElementById("openModal").class="modalDialog opend"; return false;'>>Register</a>
```

When rendering the control from server, depending on the open mode, either render it with or without the css class.

Hope this helps.